# Why does linear_sum_assignment in scipy.optimize never return if one of the assignments must have a cost of Infinity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, anaconda

When using `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`, if the cost matrix of the bipartite graph is set up in a way such that one of the assignments must have a cost of infinity, the algorithm will simply never return, and hang there forever.

In the following example, the second vertex in the first set will always have a cost of infinity regardless of which vertex in the second set it is matched with. This will cause the program to hang and never print anything.

```
cost = np.array([[np.inf, np.inf, 4], 
                 [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf], 
                 [np.inf, 4, np.inf]])
row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
print(cost)
print(col_ind)
print(cost[row_ind, col_ind].sum())
```

Yet, I would expect that we should nonetheless be able to find an assignment. For example, the second vertex in the first set can still be matched with the first vertex in the second set. We would then have a `col_ind` of `[2 0 1]` and a total cost of assignment of infinity.

**My question is, why does this happen, and how can I prevent this from happening and ensure that `linear_sum_assignment` always returns? Alternatively, is there a way to detect that this would happen, and simply not run `linear_sum_assignment`? Or are there other workarounds?**

I would also like to note that the following cost matrix will also result in the program not printing anything, so it is insufficient to simply ensure that every row have at least 1 non-infinite cost.

```
cost = np.array([[np.inf, np.inf, 4], 
                 [np.inf, 4, np.inf], 
                 [np.inf, 4, np.inf]])
```

Finally, the following cost matrix is fine

```
cost = np.array([[np.inf, np.inf, 4], 
                 [4, np.inf, np.inf], 
                 [np.inf, 4, np.inf]])
```

and results in the following output.

```
[[ inf  inf   4.]
 [  4.  inf  inf]
 [ inf   4.  inf]]
[2 0 1]
12.0
```

I don't believe this is version specific, but in the event that it is, I am running Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0.

Comment: If it never returns, it's a bug.  You can report the bug at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues by clicking on "New issue" and describing the problem.  Be sure to include the scipy version along with the rest of the information.

Comment: [Bug report has been submitted, and confirmed.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a [**bug**](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7005) in `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`.

If it is not strictly necessary for infinity to be used, a temporary workaround could be to avoid using values of infinity, and instead use an extremely large number instead. Extremely large numbers less than infinity works as expected.

Comment: it still gives the answer, for example what if all the rows have to choose that extremely large value?

Comment: @datonefaridze have a post-processing step/check to correct for those cases